# Query in a LIKE-TREE table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have a table with the following columns:

```
idCat, idParent, Des
```

idCat is autoincremented, Des is for Description and idParent can be "0" if the record is a parent or it can have "idCat" value of a parent if is child.

I need to do a query for SELECT "Des" of all record that not have a child, something like this:

```
SELECT Des FROM Table HAVING COUNT (idCat=idParent) = 0
```

Obviously this query doesn't work.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Is possible to CONCAT the Mark Bennister's resultant DES with each parent while record is not root? Example: -Apple ---Red ---Yellow Your query return Red and Yellow (is ok). But is possible to return Apple - Red and Apple - Yellow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done via a NOT IN, NOT EXISTS or LEFT JOIN ... WHERE NULL - the latter is generally the best-performing in MySQL:

```
SELECT t1.Des FROM Table t1
LEFT JOIN Table t2 on t1.idCat = t2.idParent
WHERE t2.idParent IS NULL
```

Comment: Is possible to CONCAT the resultant DES with each parent while record is not root?

Example:
-Apple
---Red
---Yellow

Your query return Red and Yellow (is ok). But is possible to return Apple - Red and Apple - Yellow?

Comment: You would need to add a join to the immediate parent - something like `JOIN Table t0 on t0.idCat = t1.idParent` - and include the parent in a concat, like `SELECT concat(t0.Des,'-',t1.Des) as CatDes`.

Comment: I need join to ALL parent not immediate parent..

If I've: 
Apple
-Red
--Good

I want to obtain Apple - Red - Good

Comment: No, not in a single query in MySQL - you would need a *recursive* query, which MySQL does not support. The accepted answer to the following question on dba.stackexchange.com shows how to achieve this through a stored procedure, in MySQL: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161

Answer (score 0):

if all of parents idParent field is 0 or null then use this query

```
SELECT Des FROM Table HAVING idParent = 0 OR idParent IS NULL
```

this would be work but slower with big db;

```
SELECT Des FROM Table HAVING idParent NOT IN ( SELECT idCat FROM Table )
```